# I'm new in java programming, I have this Battleship assignment which the width and height is a 2D Array:

Tags: java

```
public class GameBoard {


  public int[][] values;

  // Default constructor
  // No arguments, it initialises the Grid with a default value
  // of 10 rows and 10 columns
  public Grid() {
    creatingArray(10,10);
  }

  // Second constructor
  // Two arguments, it initialises the Grid with number
  // of rows and columns indicated when instantiating
  public Grid(int row, int column) {
    creatingArray(row, column);
  }

  // Third constructor
  // One argument, it initialises the Grid with same number
  // of rows and columns, as per indicated when instantiating
  public Grid(int rowcolumn) {
    creatingArray(rowcolumn, rowcolumn);
  }

  // Method to create the array
  private void creatingArray(int row, int column) {
    values = new int[row][column];
  }

  // The word override tell the compiler to use this "toString"
  // method, instead of the one in the Object class.
  // Don't worry to much about it, as you'll have a whole
  // course in inheritance and Object Oriented programming.
  @Override
  // This method will return a string to be printed on the console
  // when needed.
  public String toString() {
    String toReturn = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            toReturn = toReturn + String.valueOf(values[i][j]) + " ";
        }
        toReturn = toReturn + "\n";
    }

    return toReturn;
  }


}
```

- Allow the user to choose a grid size (Minimum 10 x 10, but can be any size up to a max of
  20x20 – just to make it realistic)
- Allow for a RECTANGULAR grid (e.g. could be 10 x 12, or 12 x 16, etc). The MINIMUM for
  each side is 10 (so you can have 10 x 16, but NOT 13 x 6, for example)
- RANDOMLY select a grid square to place the start of the Battleship. The Battleship length
  will be 1/3 of the WIDTH of the grid – rounded to the nearest whole number. (So, if the
  grid is 10 wide then the Battleship is 3 squares (10/3 = 3.3  3).
- RANDOMLY decide to place the Battleship HORIZONTALLY or VERTICALLY.
- Remember where the Battleship is placed, but NOT show it on screen
- Show a blank grid on screen at game start and ask Player 1 to choose a square by entering
  “grid co-ordinates” (e.g. row – 3, column – 4)
  Computer Programming – FINAL Assignment Page 3 of 6
- Ensure that each square can only be picked ONCE. If a player picks a square that was
  already picked, they can pick again.
- Determine if the Player’s choice “hits” the Battleship, then output “That is a hit!” (or
  similar message) and show the grid with a “H” in the relevant square (a “hit” means that
  the player chose ANY of the squares where part of the Battleship is). If it is not a hit, the
  output “That is a miss!” (or similar message) and show the grid with a “M” in the relevant
  square
- Alternate Player turns. If only one Player, then just count the number of hits and misses.
- Show the grid after each turn WITH ANY HITS AND MISSES so far on screen (but not the
  Battleship itself!)
- Count the number of Hits and Misses for each player
- End the game when ALL of the Battleship has been “Hit”
- Determine each player’s score as follows:

  - Score = Hits - (Misses * 2)
  - The player who scored the LAST hit on the Battleship gets PLUS 1 point
  - (It is possible to have a minus score in total!)
- Determine a winner based on the HIGHEST score. If scores are the same, then it is a draw.
- (If only one Player, just output their score)
  EXAMPLE – Assume 2 Players and a 10 x 10 grid, so Battleship is 3 squares

I really got stuck with this.
P.S the main method is called in another class

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask good questions here.  The fact that you're new and stuck doesn't qualify you for special treatment.  We don't do homework here.  You'll never learn if you don't try to power through.

Answer (score 0):

Asking a specific question would help you a lot more than just posting the full assignment and saying you are "stuck". I would first break down your assignment into smaller steps that you can try to tackle individually. Your first objective should be creating the actual board for the battleship game then randomly placing the battleships on to the board.

Comment: This 'answer' would be better off being put in a comment to the question.